# Generating a new IP address

Tags: proxy

I'm building a service which will need to access a certain Big Corp API which is limited to 5000 calls/24 hours from one ip address.

However I may have more than 5k customers who could need to access this api within a given day.

What is a way to overcome this? Can I use proxies or is there another way?

Comment: I don't think it belongs to ServerFault - maybe the problem could be solved by a changed design like integrating caching and stuff. But the question should be rephrased in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only condition is 5000 requests every 24h per IP, then the legal and not very expensive solution is to get a second, third or fourth IP addresses (ie, as many as you want) from which you make the requests.

It's just a matter of getting additional DSL lines. Which is a totally feasible scenario if you are (or will be) making money from this.

Answer (score 2):

Then don't use it, or arrange a deal that enables you to have more than 5000 calls. You wouldn't want to get banned for violating the t & a would you? And then you'll have 5000+ upset customers.

Or can you cache the results of the call?

Comment: Do you mean t&c instead of t&a?

Answer (score 2):

First, get a good lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

you can always reboot your router if you have dynamic IP... that's the official trick for megavideo...

Answer (score 1):

Does the API require registration? If not, could you offload the API calls to your customers? That would be my first attempt, letting the clients perform the API calls and return the result to your server as required. But it depends on the API usage policy, if this is legal.